# Result is empty. Can't get response from SOAP api using Ksoap2- android (Using Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to get respond from SOAP API using an android-Ksoap2 library. But the result is something I wouldn't expect. API works fine. I tested with POSTMAN using POST request with XML.

The Request I made with XML file was.. (namespace masked)

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <GetRealTimeStopData xmlns="******">
            <stopId>1295</stopId>
            <forceRefresh>true</forceRefresh>
        </GetRealTimeStopData>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I tried parsing SoapObject to SoapPrimitive which someone suggested. But No luck.

```
class SoapAsyncTask: AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    var URL = "******" //masking
    var NAMESPACE = "******" // masking
    var METHOD_NAME = "GetRealTimeStopData"

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {
        var result = ""
        val soapObject = SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME)

        val propertyInfo = PropertyInfo()
        propertyInfo.type = Int::class.java
        propertyInfo.name = "stopId"
        propertyInfo.value = params[0]
        soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfo)

        val propertyInfo1 = PropertyInfo()
        propertyInfo1.type = Boolean::class.java
        propertyInfo1.name = "forceRefresh"
        propertyInfo1.value = true
        soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfo1)

        Log.wtf("** DEBUG ** number of property ", soapObject.propertyCount.toString())
        Log.wtf("** DEBUG ** stopId ", soapObject.getProperty(0).toString())
        Log.wtf("** DEBUG ** forceRefresh ", soapObject.getProperty(1).toString())

        val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11)
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject)
        envelope.dotNet = false

        val httpTransportSE = HttpTransportSE(URL)

        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(getSoapAction(METHOD_NAME), envelope)
            Log.wtf("** DEBUG ** envelope.response ", envelope.response.toString())
            var resultObject: SoapObject = envelope.response as SoapObject
            var soapPrimitiveObject: SoapPrimitive = resultObject as SoapPrimitive
            result = soapPrimitiveObject.toString()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return result

    }

    override fun onPostExecute(s: String) {
        Log.wtf("** DEBUG **", s)
    }

    private fun getSoapAction(method: String): String {
        return "\"" + NAMESPACE + method + "\""
    }

}
```

and error log is following.

```
2019-05-03 13:58:57.352 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest E/** DEBUG ** number of property: 2
2019-05-03 13:58:57.374 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest E/** DEBUG ** stopId: 1295
2019-05-03 13:58:57.391 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest E/** DEBUG ** forceRefresh: true
2019-05-03 13:58:57.653 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-05-03 13:58:57.853 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest E/** DEBUG ** envelope.response: anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{}; }
2019-05-03 13:58:57.856 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive
2019-05-03 13:58:57.856 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at com.jinsoft77.soaptest.SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground(SoapAsyncTask.kt:48)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at com.jinsoft77.soaptest.SoapAsyncTask.doInBackground(SoapAsyncTask.kt:12)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-05-03 13:58:57.865 13506-13541/com.jinsoft77.soaptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue. for the future reference, I am writing down how I resolved.

This was part of the issue in my case.

```
envelope.dotNet = true
```

Full method.

```
fun getRealTimeStopData(stopId : String?, forceRefresh: String?) : MutableList<Bus> {

        var busList: MutableList<Bus> = mutableListOf()
        val METHOD_NAME = "GetRealTimeStopData"
        val SOAP_ACTION = Utils.SOAP_NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME
        val soapObject = SoapObject(Utils.SOAP_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME)

        soapObject.addProperty("stopId", stopId)
        soapObject.addProperty("forceRefresh", forceRefresh)

        val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11)
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject)

        envelope.dotNet = true // This should be TRUE *important 

        val httpTransportSE = HttpTransportSE(Utils.SOAP_URL)

        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)
            val soapPrimitive: SoapObject = envelope.response as SoapObject

            // index 1 is Stopdata.
            var data: SoapObject = soapPrimitive.getProperty(1) as SoapObject
            // get to "Document Element"
            if(data.hasProperty("DocumentElement")){
                var documentElement: SoapObject = data.getProperty("DocumentElement") as SoapObject

                for(i in 1..documentElement.propertyCount) {
                    var obj = documentElement.getProperty(i-1) as SoapObject

                    var bus = Bus()
                    bus.MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef = obj.getProperty("MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef = obj.getProperty("MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef = obj.getProperty("MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName = obj.getProperty("MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef = obj.getProperty("MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName = obj.getProperty("MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime = obj.getProperty("MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime").toString()
                    bus.MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime = obj.getProperty("MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime").toString()

                    busList.add(bus)
                }
            } else {
                Log.v("**DEBUG**","busList size : " + busList.size.toString())
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return busList
    }
```

Bus Class

```
class Bus {
    lateinit var MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef: String
    lateinit var MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef: String
    lateinit var MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef: String
    lateinit var MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName: String
    lateinit var MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef: String
    lateinit var MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName: String
    lateinit var MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime: String
    lateinit var MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime: String
}
```